# Charging bottle deposit with Shopify

Tags: checkout, shopify

I'm relatively inexperienced with Shopify, so I'm hoping it's not too difficult to do this.

I'm working on a Shopify store that sells bottles of wine. The client wants a 10¢ bottle deposit for each ordered bottle to show up as a separate line item. How might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line item is a product, so you need to make a ten cent product. Ensure for each bottle in the cart, there is a matching quantity of bottle deposit before checkout. Easy to do with the Ajax API. Note that a clever customer could theoretically remove these pesky ten cent things from their cart.

Comment: I've got a script which removes the checkout button and displays an error if the number of bottles isn't a multiple of 6, so I can display another error if the deposits aren't there. But how would I add the products in the first place? Is that what I'd use the Ajax API for? (I'm assuming there's an "add to cart" service)

Comment: It worked out pretty well. It's just hacky enough to make me worry though -- I wish Shopify had this sort of thing built in.

Comment: No matter what Carson, at some point, you have to write some code. If Shopify tried to do it all for their clients, the codebase would quickly turn into a pile of dogpoo like Magento. Better to be great at the 80% and leave 20% to the hackers. Congrats on getting it going.